# How to make network card passive

Tags: wireless, privacy

Id prefer not to have my computer send out probe requests. how do I go about turning probe requests off? Will this impede my wifi connect-ability in any way?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to turn probe requests off is to turn off your wireless antenna. If you turn it off somehow in the hardware then you wouldn't be able to associate to any wireless network.

For privacy you could use tools that change your mac address. This is a way to help stay anonymous and private.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AnonymizingNetworkMACAddresses

Comment: ive been using macchanger but for the life of me I havent been able to get the automatic feature to work so i've been having to do it manually. But recently I realized that my real address was still getting submitted